# How to prove conservation of tensor of angular momentum using symmetry of stress energy tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

Stress energy tensor looks like this
$$
T_{\mu}^{\nu}=\partial_{\mu} \phi^{a} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\left(\partial_{\nu} \phi^{a}\right)}-\delta_{\mu}^{\nu} \mathcal{L}+\partial_{\lambda} f_{\mu}^{\nu \lambda}, \quad f_{\mu}^{\nu \lambda}=-f_{\mu}^{\lambda \nu}
$$
$$
T^{\mu \nu}=T^{\nu \mu}
$$
And I need to prove the conservation of this tensor
$$
J^{\mu \nu}=\int d^{d-1} x\left(x^{\mu} T^{\nu 0}-x^{\nu} T^{\mu 0}\right) 
$$
$$
\dot{J}^{\mu \nu}=0
$$
At first, I found derivative, but can't do anything with it
$$
\dot{J}^{\mu \nu}=\partial_{0}\left(\int d^{d-1} x\left(x^{\mu} T^{\nu 0}-x^{\nu} T^{\mu 0}\right)\right)=\int d^{d-1} x\left(\delta_{0}^{\mu} T^{\nu 0}-\delta_{0}^{\nu} T^{\mu 0}+x^{\mu} \partial_{0} T^{\nu 0}-x^{\nu} \partial_{0} T^{\mu 0}\right)
$$

Comment: You actually want to prove $\partial_\mu J^{\mu\nu}=0$.

Comment: it is not the same as $\partial_0 J^{\mu\nu}=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $K^{\mu\nu\lambda} \equiv x^\mu T^{\nu\lambda}-x^\nu T^{\mu\lambda}$. Then using the conservation of energy momentum $\partial_\lambda T^{\mu\lambda} =0$, $$\partial_\lambda K^{\mu\nu\lambda} = \delta^\mu_\lambda T^{\nu\lambda}-\delta^{\nu}_{\lambda}T^{\mu\lambda}=T^{\nu\mu} - T^{\mu\nu}=0$$
Then we can integrate this over a 3D spatial slice, and the $\lambda=0$ piece is what you are asking about
$$\int d^3x \partial_\lambda K^{\mu\nu\lambda} = \partial_0 J^{\mu\nu}+ \int d^3 x \partial_i K^{\mu\nu i} =  \partial_0 J^{\mu\nu} = 0$$
where the term involve the spatial derivatives $\partial_i$ became a boundary term which we are taking to vanish as usual.

Comment: So, you are implying that
$$\int_V d^{3} x \partial_{i} K^{\mu \nu i}=\oint_{\partial V}\left(K^{\mu\nu1}dydz+K^{\mu\nu2}dzdx+K^{\mu\nu3}dxdy\right)=0$$
because $K\rightarrow 0$ on big distances?

Comment: @delchB, yep, exactly

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: What's the downvote for?

Comment: it's not me....

Answer (score 2):

Since $J^{\mu\nu}$ is a definite integral over all but the time dimension,$$\begin{align}\partial_\mu J^{\mu\nu}&=\partial_0J^{0\nu}\\&=\int d^{d-1}x\partial_0(x^0T^{\nu0}-x^\nu T^{00})\\&=\int d^{d-1}x(T^{\nu0}+x^0\partial_0T^{\nu0}-\delta_0^\nu T^{00}-x^\nu\partial_0T^{00}),\end{align}$$whence $\partial_\mu J^{\mu0}=0$ and$$\begin{align}\partial_\mu J^{\mu i}&=\int d^{d-1}x(T^{i0}+x^0\partial_0T^{i0}-x^i\partial_0T^{00})\\&\stackrel{1}{=}\int d^{d-1}x(T^{i0}-x^0\partial_jT^{ij}+x^i\partial_jT^{0j})\\&\stackrel{2}{=}\int d^{d-1}x(T^{i0}-\delta_i^jT^{0j})\\&\stackrel{3}{=}0,\end{align}$$where $\stackrel{1}{=}$ uses $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$, $\stackrel{2}{=}$ uses integration by parts, and $\stackrel{3}{=}$ uses $T^{\mu\nu}=T^{\nu\mu}$. So $\partial_\mu J^{\mu\nu}=0$. We [usually quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Special_relativity) conservation laws for symmetric rank-$2$ tensors in the form $\partial_\mu J^{\mu\nu}=0$, which manifestly transforms as a vector.

Comment: but $$\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu\nu}=\partial_{0}J^{0\nu}+\partial_{1}J^{1\nu}+\partial_{2}J^{2\nu}+\partial_{3}J^{3\nu}$$
You didn't prove that $\partial_{1}J^{1\nu}+\partial_{2}J^{2\nu}+\partial_{3}J^{3\nu}=0$

Comment: @delchB Please re-read my points about integration.

Comment: so $\partial_{1} J^{1 \nu}+\partial_{2} J^{2 \nu}+\partial_{3} J^{3 \nu}=0$ because J doesn't obviously depend on x?

Comment: @delchB It doesn't depend on spatial coordinates, full stop.

Comment: but where is here $\partial_0J^{\mu\nu}$...

Comment: I wasn't going to say anything, because I thought my answer was clear enough, but just to be clear, in this case the three-index $K^{\mu\nu\lambda}$ tensor is like the conserved current, and the $J^{\mu\nu}$ that OP is asking about are more like charges, hence the time derivative. This whole set up is very non-covariant, notice the $x^\mu$ coordinate 'vectors' in the definition.

Comment: @octonion Did you mean to leave that comment here? It would make more sense under your answer, which is indeed clear.